# Retrieving a DOM value from Elm ports

Tags: elm

My elm app uses an auto scrolling function, which gets the Y position of an element and uses [Dom.Scroll](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.0/Dom-Scroll).toY to scroll there.

Two do this, I set up two ports; a subscription and sender.

ports.elm

```
port setYofElementById : Maybe String -> Cmd msg
port getYofElementById : (Value -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

index.html

```
app.ports.setYofElementById.subscribe(function(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  app.ports.getYofElementById.send({"number": rect.top});
})
```

The listener is a subscription

```
subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Ports.getYofElementById getYofElementById

getYofElementById : Decode.Value -> Msg
getYofElementById value =
    let
        result =
            Decode.decodeValue bSimpleIntValueDecoder value
    in
    case result of
        Ok simpleIntValue ->
            SetSelectedElementYPosition (Just simpleIntValue.number)

        Err id ->
            SetSelectedElementYPosition Nothing
```

`SetSelectedElementYPosition` just sets the model.

Now, the action that executes this does two things: call `Port.setYofElementById`, then scrolls to the Y value in the model, assuming that it has already been set.

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of

        ScrollToY idString ->
            model
                => Cmd.batch
                    [ Ports.setYofElementById (Just idString)
                    , Task.attempt (always NoOp) <| Dom.Scroll.toY "ul" model.selectedElementYPosition
                    ]
```

However, this doesn't happen sequentially.  When the action first fires, nothing happens.  If I fire it again, it scrolls to the location called for in the first action.  So it seems like it is calling `Dom.Scroll.toY` before the value is set.

Is there a way to force the `Cmd`s in `ScrollToY` to happen in sequence?  Or is there a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work by tacking the action for `Task.attempt (always NoOp) <| Dom.Scroll.toY "ul" model.selectedElementYPosition` onto the action called by the **subscription**, not the action.  That's the key.

With ports, the `subscribe` and `send` actions follow completely different pathways, so anything that reacts to a `send` from js to elm is not going to be referenced in the actions that go from elm to js.

In this case, since `SetSelectedElementYPosition` is being called from the subscription, you have to set the update there:

```
    SetSelectedElementYPosition idString ->
       ({model | selectedElementYPosition = number }, Cmd.none)
            |> andThen update GoToSelectedElementYPosition
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `Cmd`s to execute in sequence by making the second, the one that does the `Dom.Scroll.toY`, happen as a response to the first, the one that does the `setYofElementById`.  The following update function accomplishes this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ScrollToY idString ->
            (model, Ports.setYofElementById idString)
        SetSelectedElementYPosition (Just newY) -> 
            (model, Task.attempt (always NoOp) <| Dom.Scroll.toY "ul" newY)
        SetSelectedElementYPosition Nothing -> 
            (model, Cmd.none)
        NoOp -> 
            (model, Cmd.none)
```

With the `Cmd`s correctly sequenced, you will need to make sure that the `newY` argument to `Dom.Scroll.toY` is in the correct frame of reference to get the effect that you want.

Comment: Sequencing is key.  The big, counter-intuitive hurdle that was there is no way (I think) to sequence the scroll action relative to the initial action that makes the port call from elm to js; it can only be done relative to the subscription, because they are different causal branches.  See my answer.